# GIT push error de auntenticacion

Tags: nodejs, git, github, git-push, gitlab

hola a todos cuando ingreso en ubuntu 18.04 lts para clonar una carpeta de un repositorio gitlab todo esta bien, el problema viene cuando quiero hacer Push me lanza un error
dice acceso denegado, mi cuenta y la contraseña son las correctas por que ya me asegure de que con ellas puedo entrar desde mi navegador probe hasta con 3, este mismo error me lo lanza en windows 10 y ahi tambien incluso borraba las credenciales, de verdad ya no se que hacer solo me lo hace en gitlab, ya borre carpetas, intente subir todo al repositorio sin clonarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

incluso ya habia generado una llave ssh pero cuando hago la peticion para ver si todo esta bien me lanza el siguiente error:
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de verdad ya no se que hacer, estoy en fase de entrenamiento en una empresa :'v

Comment: ¿Sólo `git push`? ¿A qué rama vas a hacer el `push`? Debes decirle a `git` a qué rama lo harás. Por ejemplo `git push origin master`. Eso hará un `push` a la rama `master` de `origin`. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Una vez generada la clave SSH la estás introduciendo en GitLab en el área de claves SSH?

Para hacerlo vas a tu foto de perfil->ajustes->claves SSH-> Pegas la calve SSH generada que suele comenzar por ssh-rsa.

Asegúrate de que comience por ssh-rsa (si estás generando este tipo de clave, y que acaba con tu email, si no te dará problemas.